# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on UICollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

This one has stumped me.

```
func updateCollectionView() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        if let strongSelf = self {
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            let minimumSpacing: CGFloat = 8
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumSpacing
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = minimumSpacing
            let dim = strongSelf.view.frame.width / CGFloat(strongSelf.size) - minimumSpacing
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: dim, height: dim)
            strongSelf.collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
            strongSelf.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

When it tries to setCollectionViewLayout, I get :

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x800000000)
```

collectionView, strongSelf and layout are all valid objects. This also happens only when strongSelf.size is less than 4, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this one was a weird one for me, but I solved it using this gentleman's post:

http://jaymayu.com/uicollectionview-and-dynamically-changing-layouts-on-runtime/

Basically, I had to do this:

```
strongSelf.gridCollectionView.reloadData()
strongSelf.gridCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
strongSelf.gridCollectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
```

What mattered was that reloadData() needed to be before setCollectionViewLayout. I'll need to think about exactly why this is, but this solved the problem.